# Получить относительный путь с абсолютного (возвращен glob)

Tags: php

Получил массив с путями с помощью метода glob. Он возвращает абсолютные пути.
Есть ли встроенная возможность конвертировать эти пути в относительные для использования в ссылках?

Вот что возвращает glob:

```
glob( __DIR__ . "/src/tests/*/*.php");

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(69) "/works/domains/test.com/src/tests/test1/index.php"
  [1]=>
  string(69) "/works/domains/test.com/src/tests/test2/index.php"
}
```

Мне же нужно, чтобы пути были относительными от домена:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(69) "/src/tests/test1/index.php"
  [1]=>
  string(69) "/src/tests/test2/index.php"
}
```

Comment: может неправильно выразился - он возвращает путь от корня файловой системы, а не от корня сайта(домена). И вот этот путь является по сути абсолютным

Comment: Дополните вопрос строкой поиска `glob`

Comment: Дополнил. Если указывать в методе glob путь формата домен-путь `http://test.com/src/tests/*/*.php`, то никаких фалов не находит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ( glob( __DIR__ . "/src/tests/*/*.php") as $value )
        {
            echo basename($value) . '<br>';
        }
```

В таком варианте он найдет в указанной папке все файлы и выведет их. Естественно вы можете в цикле делать что хотите. В том числе добавить относительную или абсолютную ссылку

Вот вариант замены корня, должно сработать:

```
foreach ( glob( __DIR__ . "/src/tests/*/*.php") as $value )
{
    echo str_replace(__DIR__ , "/", $value) . '<br>';
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ad704285886e191c14441e3d764974b6d3d0100

Comment: Вы не поняли. То, что я могу пройтись и вырезать то, что мне нужно, я в курсе. Меня интересует, есть ли возможность стандартными методами получить с абсолютного пути получить относительный от домена. Т.е. с `"/works/domains/test.com/src/tests/test1/index.php"` получить `"/src/tests/test1/index.php"`

Comment: Не понимаю задачи, что мешает добавить самому относительную ссылку. Вы по ней и ищите вначале, вынесите ее в переменную и добавляйте при поиске и при выводе.

Comment: я ищу по шаблону! Этот шаблон соответствует и этому `/src/tests/test1/index.php` и этому `/src/tests/misc/index.php`

Comment: хмм... не заметил изначально тогда можно replace сделать, сейчас добавлю вариант в ответе